# Fatal error: (Data Base)

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, database

So i have this problem were i keep getting the "**Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\AppServ\www\elimina_cliente.php on line 35**" message, this is the code in the line 35:

**LINE 35**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($T_C)+mysql_fetch_array($C_C)+mysql_fetch_array($D_C)){
```

And this is the rest of the code

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
    include("Conectarse.php"); 
    $link=Conectarse(); 

    mysql_query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0", $link);
    $aidi=$_GET['id'];

    $T_C=mysql_query("SELECT 
        cliente.id_cliente, cliente.nombre_cliente, cliente.app_cliente, cliente.apm_cliente, cliente.descripcion_cliente,
        telefono_cliente.id_cliente, telefono_cliente.id_telefono,
        telefono.id_telefono, telefono.numero_telefono, telefono.descripcion_telefono
        FROM cliente
        INNER JOIN telefono_cliente ON cliente.id_cliente = telefono_cliente.id_cliente
        INNER JOIN telefono ON telefono_cliente.id_telefono = telefono.id_telefono
        WHERE cliente.id_cliente = $aidi", $link);

    $C_C=mysql_query("SELECT
        cliente.id_cliente, cliente.nombre_cliente, cliente.app_cliente, cliente.apm_cliente, cliente.descripcion_cliente,
        correo_cliente.id_correo, correo_cliente.id_cliente,
        correo.id_correo, correo.email, correo.descripcion_correo
        FROM cliente
        INNER JOIN correo_cliente ON cliente.id_cliente=correo_cliente.id_correo
        INNER JOIN correo ON correo_cliente.id_correo=correo.id_correo
        WHERE cliente.id_cliente=$aidi", $link);

    $D_C=mysql_query("SELECT
        cliente.id_cliente, cliente.nombre_cliente, cliente.app_cliente, cliente.apm_cliente, cliente.descripcion_cliente,
        direccion_cliente.id_cliente, direccion_cliente.id_direccion,
        direccion.id_direccion, direccion.nombre_calle, direccion.num_int, direccion.num_ext, direccion.descripcion_direccion
        FROM cliente
        INNER JOIN direccion_cliente ON cliente.id_cliente=direccion_cliente.id_cliente
        INNER JOIN direccion ON direccion_cliente.id_direccion=direccion.id_direccion
        WHERE cliente.id_cliente=$aidi", $link);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($T_C)+mysql_fetch_array($C_C)+mysql_fetch_array($D_C)){
        if (isset($row)) {
            $delete=mysql_query("DELETE FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente='$aidi'", $link);
            $deleteTelefono=mysql_query("DELETE FROM telefono WHERE id_telefono='$row[id_telefono]'", $link);
            $deleteTelefono_Cliente=mysql_query("DELETE FROM telefono_cliente WHERE id_cliente='$row[id_cliente]' AND id_telefono = '$row[id_telefono]'", $link);
            $deleteCorreo=mysql_query("DELETE FROM correo WHERE id_correo='$row[id_correo]'",$link);
            $deleteCorreo_Cliente=mysql_query("DELETE FROM correo_cliente WHERE id_cliente='$row[correo]' AND id_correo = '$row[id_correo]'", $link);
            $deleteDireccion=mysql_query("DELETE FROM direccion WHERE id_direccion='$row[id_direccion]'",$link);
            $deleteDireccion_Cliente=mysql_query("DELETE FROM direccion_cliente WHERE id_cliente='$row[id_direccion]' AND id_direccion = '$row[id_direccion]'", $link);

            echo "<script>alert('Eliminación exitosa');</script>";
            echo "<script>location.href='clientes.php'</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

My logic on this code is to put the inner joins on variables and then make the variables into arrays and concatenate the arrays so i have to work with only one array, the code worked when i create more clients and then delete them, but when i only have one left i can't delete him and the Fatal Error appears. I really don't know what is my error, help please. And sorry if bad English

Comment: That line is clearly not valid PHP. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: I was trying to "put the inner joins on variables and then make the variables into arrays and concatenate the arrays so i have to work with only one array"